# How to Connect Langchain Database Agent with SqlServer

Tags: python, sql-server, langchain, py-langchain

I need to connect my langchain database agent with my sqlserver database so that my agent can access the data, yet in the [documention](https://python.langchain.com/docs/integrations/toolkits/sql_database)  it does not explain how to do so, it only shows how to connect to sqlite like the following code:

```
from langchain.agents import create_sql_agent
from langchain.agents.agent_toolkits import SQLDatabaseToolkit
from langchain.sql_database import SQLDatabase
from langchain.llms.openai import OpenAI
from langchain.agents import AgentExecutor
from langchain.agents.agent_types import AgentType
from langchain.chat_models import ChatOpenAI


db = SQLDatabase.from_uri("sqlite:///../../../../../notebooks/Chinook.db")
toolkit = SQLDatabaseToolkit(db=db, llm=OpenAI(temperature=0))
```

I have tried to replace this code:

```
db = SQLDatabase.from_uri("sqlite:///../../../../../notebooks/Chinook.db")
```

with this:

```
db = SQLDatabase.from_uri("mssql+pyodbc://{server}/{database}?driver{driver}")
```

but the following error showed up:

> sqlalchemy.exc.InterfaceError: (pyodbc.InterfaceError) ('IM002', '[IM002] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified (0) (SQLDriverConnect)')
> (Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/20/rvf5)**

Comment: Have you contacted the vendor to see if they even support SQL Server? That might be the reason you don't see an example in the documentation.

Comment: @AaronBertrand Indeed they do

Comment: Ok, so did you ask their support team _how to do it_? I've never heard of this product before and I doubt many others here have either. So I would still start with the vendor.

Comment: Some basic guidance is here [https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/core/engines.html#microsoft-sql-server] (`SQLDatabase is a wrapper around a SQLAlchemy engine, as the error message suggests).

Comment: Have you tried `driver={driver}`? And what's stored in the `driver` variable? e.g.: if you have ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server installed then it should end up with `driver=ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server` encoded in the URI as `driver=ODBC+Driver+17+for+SQL+Server` Ref: [SQLAlchemy # Microsoft SQL Server](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/dialects/mssql.html#module-sqlalchemy.dialects.mssql.pyodbc)

Answer (score 0):

I've tested this and it seems to be working.

```
uri = 'mssql+pyodbc://DBUsername:DBPassword@ServerName:Port/DBName?driver=ODBC+Driver+17+for+SQL+Server'
db = SQLDatabase.from_uri(uri)
```

Ref : https://github.com/langchain-ai/langchain/issues/9804

Comment: the link of the github issue which you provided is made by me lol, I am programmersEmperor. Thanks anyway